# VS10 C++ Error C2833: 'operator string' is not a recognized operator or type

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to have a custom operator `operator ""_exp` for `Exponent` class that I could call the operator like this:

```
std::cout << 10.5 * 2._exp << '\n';
```

**My rest of the code:**

```
struct Exponent
{
    long double value;
};

Exponent operator ""_exp(long double exponent)
{
    return exponent;
}
```

I am using **Visual Studio 10** compiler and I get a **C2883** error:

```
Error C2833: 'operator string' is not a recognized operator or type
```

**I have tried:**

I've found a list of possible user-defined operators but I couldn't find `operator ""`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ds533389(v%3dvs.100)

**Question:**
Can somebody tell my is it possible to have `operator ""_exp"` in **Visual Studio 2010**? Or maybe there is another way to achieve this?

Comment: `10.5 ** 2._exp` there is no `operator**` in c++

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot - But you can write an type with unary `operator *` that returns a type implementing binary `*`.

Comment: You need to update your visual studio if you want full support of C++11 features.

Comment: I need to have `Exponent a = 123_exp;`. Are you talking about the same problem?

Comment: @StoryTeller could you tell me if VS12 will fit for that? And could you tell me how this C++11 feature is called?

Comment: It's called "user-defined literals". And fairly full list of feature support by vendors is given here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support - IIUC VS12 wouldn't support it either.

Comment: Understood, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Visual Studio 10 is not a C++11 compiler.

Their first compiler that fully supports C++11 (including therefore *user defined literals* which is what you are attempting to use) is MSVC2017.

Finally, note that `10.5` is a `double`, *not* a `long double`.

Comment: Actually, it is not correct to say that is not a C++11 compiler. This example is not mine, I just tested out. You are missing the point with the 3rd sentence. But thanks though.